# jenkins release plugin compatible with multipipeline job

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-release-plugin, gradle-release-plugin

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin

Right now we have jenkins release plugin that works with freestyle jobs. Any idea if we have release plugin compatible with mutlibranch and multipipeline jobs.

I just want Release button to be there on Jenkins job and on clicking, it should work as build button do. I have release functionality defined in Jenkinsfile.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Release plugin is compatible already with jenkins pipeline, more information in [this Jenkins ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40765).

You can just use the [release step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/release/) from your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks hakamairi, as per ticket, it was released in 2.7 but I have release plugin 2.10.1 installed and I don't see Release button being display.

Comment: So if I understand u correctly, the release button will only be available when we configure release step in Jenkinsfile. If so, could you please provide example code of release plugin configuration. The link is not informative, neither I could generate code from pipeline syntax

Comment: I am using pipeline syntax to generate code but it says 'WorkflowJob does not implement BuildableItemWithBuildWrappers'. How do I solve this